# Why I got an error "must be caught or declared to be thrown"?

Tags: java, for-loop

```
import java.io.*;

public class prelab7 {

   public static void readstring(String a){

    String s = "EECS 132";

    StringReader s1 = new StringReader(s);
    for (int n = 0; n < s.length(); n = n + 1){

        char c = (char)s1. read();
        System.out.print(" " + c);
    }
  }
}
```

1 error found:
File: /Users/clara/Desktop/EECS132/prelab7.java  [line: 8]
Error: /Users/clara/Desktop/EECS132/prelab7.java:8: unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: Read and then post the entire error message.

Comment: Is it your IDE that's complaining or the compiler? Anyway `read()` throws an `IOException` (or something similar) which must be caught in your code.

Comment: [The Catch or Specify Requirement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `StringReader` is a `Reader`. And a `Reader`'s `.read()` method [can throw an `IOException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read%28%29).

You need to change your method declaration to:

```
public static void readstring(String a)
    throws IOException
{
    // code here
}
```

(edit: or use try/catch, as mentioned in comments; if you do so however, please avoid the classical `.printStackTrace()` with nothing else)

Comment: @OP, For example, what if the file "EECS 132" doesn't exist?  The Reader will throw an exception.

Comment: @user949300 well, here, it is barely a `String` so it doesn't really matter... Note that if we really wanted to be pedantic, we could also mention that a `Reader` is a `Closeable`, and as such you should systematically `.close()` it...

Comment: Good point - I misread the code slightly too...  Make that "what if `s` were an empty string?"